# Force Polars to store Python dictionary as pl.Object

Tags: python-polars

I am running into the dreaded "struct orders must remain the same" with a dictionary nested in my record. However, for my use case, I don't care about creating a Polars struct, I am OK with just storing a pl.Object of the original dictionary. However, my attempt to do so is not working:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    data=c.fetchall(),
    columns=[
        ("primary_key", pl.Int32),
        ("string_col", pl.Object),
        ("dict_col", pl.Object),
    ],
)
```

However, this is still raising an exception:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ComputeError(Borrowed("struct orders must remain the same"))', /Users/runner/work/polars/polars/polars/polars-core/src/frame/row.rs:457:86
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File:
    df = pl.DataFrame(
  File "venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py", line 299, in __init__
    self._df = sequence_to_pydf(
  File "venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/construction.py", line 612, in sequence_to_pydf
    pydf = PyDataFrame.read_rows(data, infer_schema_length)
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ComputeError(Borrowed("struct orders must remain the same"))
```

This is with polars 0.14.18